# How To know status of a file whether it is in processing or not in java which is platform independent?

Tags: java, file

In File Monitoring process if one file came and it is processed immediately it does not check
if file is open and writing something..Then how to prevent moving of file without closing the file.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail for your problem? Explain what do you mean by File Monitoring process and maybe show some code for what you are trying to solve.

Comment: @marcelo-hernandez-rishmawy: when file is created in some folder it will be immediately pulls out from that folder, without verifying whether the file is in open and writing something....

Comment: If you are trying to pass messages between applications, why not use a messaging system like JMS?  Using files systems to pass information between processes is not simple to get right because filesystems are not designed to do this.

Comment: At a minimum, you should probably mention what program you are using to do the file monitoring. And if its home grown please post relevant code (in particular, the code that determines when a new file has been posted to the directory being watched).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the program that's putting the files in the directory?  Put something like ".partial" on the end of the filename while the file is still being written, and then rename it to remove the ".partial" when the writing is done.  If you make the Java file-monitoring program ignore files whose names end in ".partial", it'll only see files after they've been fully written out.